# Dynamic port setting for my dockerized microservice

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, microservices, amazon-ecs

I want to deploy several instances of my microservice which uses certain port but make it scalable and not fix the port in task definition / Dockerfile. My microservice can listen to port provided in environment variable or command line.

At the moment all microservices are described in AWS ECS task definitions and have static port assignment.
Every microservice registers itself with Eureka server and now I can run multiple service instances only on different EC2 instances.

I want to be able to run several containers on the same EC2 instance but  every new service instance shall get some free port to listen to it.

What is the standard way of implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the host port to 0 in the task definition:

> If using containers in a task with the EC2 launch type, you can
>   specify a non-reserved host port for your container port mapping (this
>   is referred to as **static host port mapping**), or you can omit the
>   hostPort (or set it to 0) while specifying a container port and your
>   container automatically receives a port (this is referred to as
>   **dynamic host port mapping**) in the ephemeral port range for your
>   container instance operating system and Docker version.

[image]

> The default ephemeral port range is 49153–65535, and this range is
>   used for Docker versions before 1.6.0. For Docker version 1.6.0 and
>   later, the Docker daemon tries to read the ephemeral port range from
>   /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range (which is 32768–61000 on the
>   latest Amazon ECS-optimized AMI)

So you will need application LB in such case to route traffic on the dynamic port.

You can take help from this article [dynamic-port-mapping-in-ecs-with-application-load-balancer](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/dynamic-port-mapping-in-ecs-with-application-load-balancer/).

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Is there a way to let the service know its dynamic port number? Some environment variable/macros?
I'm using Eureka for service discovery and would register my service with its dynamic port there.

Comment: you can call AWS api for that may be